# Although reports mentioned at least three survivors, a provincial health minister said at least 37 people had died, amid fears of many more casualties

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A Pakistan International Airlines aeroplane with 99 people on board crashed in a residential area of Karachi. The aircraft had taken off from Lahore. **Although reports mentioned at least three survivors, a provincial health minister said at least 37 people had died, amid fears of many more casualties.** Pakistan had just resumed domestic flights after a coronavirus lockdown.

---

3 alive but more could be died, then the minister said yes 37 had died.

- I don't find any "but" meaning here against what the reports said, even there is a "although". What's the logic?
- does the "fears" come from the public though it is not mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not "but" logic. Rather, it is "but" psychology.

Reports talked about survivors. That is optimistic; we can hope that many more have survived.

The minister talked about many deaths. That is pessimistic; we must fear that yet more have died.

It is mathematically true that three survivors and thirty seven dead, out of ninety nine passengers, do not form a **logical** contradiction. Language, however, reflects emotions more often than it reflects the cold rigor of symbolic logic. The "but" reflects contrary emotional responses, hope and fear, to different reports.